# How validation on module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, module, translate

I'm doing a job where with Angular 8, I have to use the translate to do the translations in my app,
 as I use JIT compiler I had to do it this way, but I still have a doubt, the way I did it takes the fixed translation, 
I was wondering if there are any way for me to do a validation here inside the module.
below my code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Hello } from './app.component.ts';

// Using SystemJs' text plugin
import translations from './messages.fr.xlf!text';
const localeId = 'fr';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    Hello
  ],
  bootstrap: [ Hello ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: localeId }
  ]
});
```

I have several files of translations and would like to validate based on the language of the browser, using navigator.language

Comment: Hi Bruno, so you want to test the code? As in unit testing?

Comment: in fact i was wondering if i can validate other translation files inside my module.ts